# Можно ли перебросить свободное место с 1 раздела ЖД на другой?

Tags: windows, железо, hdd

Есть физический диск, который разбит на 2 раздела.

На одном разделе стоит винда, а на другом файловая помойка.

Можно ли перебросить свободное место с одного раздела на другой(системный) без переразбиения и потери данных?

Comment: Да, можно. Скорее всего поможет соответствующая утилита от Парагона или Акрониса.

Comment: Перебросить можно файлы, а не свободное место. Без переразметки.

Comment: @post_zeew А еще можно использовать свободную (в данном контексте читай бесплатную) Linux утилиту gparted :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, Можно. А может быть даже и diskmgmt.msc подойдет.

Answer (score 5):

Опыт многочисленных компьютерщиков говорит следующее - никогда не знаешь, когда сбойнёт. Иными словами, даже самая вылизанная и сто раз проверенная методика на сто первый раз выкинет фортель, и появится вопрос "HELP!!! Как спасти данные???". Вот только с очень большой долей вероятности будет поздно.

Крайне настоятельно рекомендую вне зависимости от того, какие средства и методика будут выбраны, начать с полного резервного копирования на внешний носитель всего, что представляет интерес, и проверки этой резервной копии на целостность. И даже если судьба вдруг повернётся задом, будет не так больно.

Ну и собственно по самой процедуре. Сначала убедитесь, что деление на разделы соответствует тому, что Вы про него думаете. Что там нет, например, расширенного раздела или скрытого системного. Программы - они, конечно, умные, но дуры. Да, изменение размеров разделов есть переразбиение в полный рост - это так, о терминологиях. Опять же если размеры разделов позволяют, то перемещение на загрузочный раздел ВСЕХ данных файлопомойки, удаление её раздела, изменение размера загрузочного раздела, а потом создание нового раздела под помойку - гораздо более безопасный вариант, пусть он и потребует две перезагрузки (да, если есть вариант с ребутом или без него - всегда выбирайте первое).

А ещё - заранее приготовьте любой загрузочный носитель (установочный диск, загрузочная флешка и т.п), причём проверьте, что с него ВАШ комп грузится, и тома с диска видны, а также что имеются средства для восстановления загрузочных областей. лучше пусть не пригодится, чем не будет.